# Почему setBackground для item в QListWidget не работает совместно с styleSheet?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Создал окно с помощью Qt Designer, в нем же описал стиль для списка:

```
QListWidget{
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 10%;
    background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.148, y1:0.0852273, x2:0.125, y2:1, stop:0.386364 rgba(252, 252, 252, 255), stop:1 rgba(174, 214, 254, 255));
    font: 12pt "Times New Roman";
}
QListWidget::item{
    background-color:blue;
}
QListWidget::item:first{
    border: 0px;
    border-top-left-radius:5%;
    border-top-right-radius:5%;
}
QListWidget::item:last{
    border: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5%;
    border-bottom-right-radius:5%;
}
```

В самом коде программы в зависимости от значения к тексту, должен манятся цвет выделения item:

```
def set_row_in_list(text_from_db):
    # Метод для выравнивания значений в списке по горизонтали и вертикали
    item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
    item.setData(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, text_from_db)
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
    return item

def load_data_for_stamps():
    stamps_info = ['F', 'D', 'K', 'E']
    for stmap_name in stamps_info:
        item = set_row_in_list(stmap_name)
        if stmap_name == 'F':
            item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(168, 255, 55, 100))
        else:
            item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(168, 0, 0, 100))
        self.stamps_listWidget.addItem(item)
```

Однако когда запускаю программу функция setBackground не отрабатывается так как нужно, либо ее полностью перекрывает стиль, также пробовал перенести установку стиля в код, ситуация не изменилась. А если убрать стиль для item, то я не представляю как установить скругления для границ верхнего и нижнего значения в списке. Да и к тому же хотел еще изменить стиль при выделении значения(selected) в списке.

Заранее благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.